# Trying to get only the odd values from a vector using the integer division with one-digit decimal numbers

Tags: r

I need to create a new object containing only the odd numbers from a variable of a dataset.

In this case I refer to the `iris` dataset and the variable `Sepal.Length`. The values of that variable are decimal with just one digit after the comma.

I take only the first 6 as an example:

```
vect_ex <- c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4)
```

What I do not understand is that the modular division seems to work on a single number:

```
5.1 %% 0.2
# [1] 0.1
```

But not when I am using it in the indexing process:

```
vect_ex[vect_ex %% 0.2 == 0.1]
# numeric(0)
```

I know what I am doing is not the best way and neither the most efficient. Still, I am trying to learn R and I want to understand what is wrong with my code.

**Moreover**, the solution proposed for this exercise uses: `iris[c(T,F),1]` and I don't really understand how it works. Thanks.

Comment: This is to do with floating point equality. Check out the unexpected result of `5.1 %% 0.2 == 0.1`

Comment: Incidentally, the proposed solution gets the odd numbered _rows_ from the data set (i.e. the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc.) . This is because the `c(T, F)` gets recycled, so the expression effectively becomes the same as `iris[c(T,F,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,F ...), 1]`. This selects every odd-numbered row from the first column of `iris`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess the question of the exercise was poorly written since it seemed I had to find the odd values of the numbers in column Sepal.Length.